# php Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Router' not found in

Tags: php

```
<?php
$query = require 'core/bootstrap.php';
$router = new Router();
require 'routes.php';
$uri = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/');   
require $router->direct($uri);
```

I don't get what I missed, tried to require `Router.php` file but nothing help searched for google for that error bug was getting only cake.php answers

```
$router ->define([

   ' ' =>'controllers/index.php',
   'about' => 'controllers/about.php',
   'about/culture' => 'controllers/about-culture.php',
   'contact' => 'controllers/contact.php'
]);
```

that's     routes.php file

Comment: What framework are you using? Is an autoloader active?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using a `Router` class without any namespace?

Comment: router class is in core folder but I don't use any namespace

Comment: router class is in core folder but I don't use any namespace

Answer (score 3):

Hey You are requiring routes.php after new Router(); line. I assume your Router class is present in routes.php file 
Hence try below code

```
$query = require 'core/bootstrap.php';

require 'routes.php';

$router = new Router();

$uri = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/');   
require $router->direct($uri);
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: router in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject2\routes.php on line 3

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function define() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject2\routes.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject2\index.php(10): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject2\routes.php on line 3    got that arror after changing to code u suggested

Comment: Now the error is in routes.php, which is what I am getting from your current comment , Check the line number 3 of routes.php or else update  question with routes.php file to see us what is going wrong.